# Different Timer with milliseconds

Tags: actionscript-3

Since Im new in AS3 I have this countdown timer that displays in a single digit "10" seconds, but my client wants to them to display like in 10:00 (4 digits) with milliseconds.

[UPDATED] http://magnixsolutions.com/clients/OT/9995MB-Scoreboard-NCR-728x90.swf - Right now the countdown is showing like 09.32:93 then 08:34 THEN 07:34:91 back and froth when it counting down and then it stopped to 00:00. It should display 4 digits.

Heres my codes that displays in "10" seconds [UPDATED]

```
import flash.text.TextField;

var fullTime:int = 10000; // 10 seconds
var updateRate:int = 25; // 60 fps update rate
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000 / updateRate, fullTime / 1000 * updateRate);
var time_txt:TextField = new TextField();
myTimer.start();

myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, countdown);

function countdown(e:TimerEvent):void {
    var dt = myTimer.delay * myTimer.repeatCount - myTimer.currentCount * myTimer.delay;
    var seconds = dt / 1000;
    var ms = (dt % 1000) * 0.1; //chop to hundredths
    timer_txt.text = ((seconds < 10) ? "0" + seconds : seconds) + ":" + ((ms < 10) ? "0" +  ms : ms); //format
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most comments in the code. Feel free to change fps update rate, There is no sense in 60 fps update rate if you have 25 fps flash application.

```
var fullTime:int = 10000; //10 seconds
var updateRate:int = 60; //60 fps update rate
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000 / updateRate, fullTime / 1000 * updateRate);
var dt:Number, seconds:int, ms:int;

var timer_txt:TextField = new TextField();
myTimer.start();

myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, countdown);

function countdown(e:TimerEvent):void {
    dt = myTimer.delay * myTimer.repeatCount - myTimer.currentCount * myTimer.delay;
    seconds = dt / 1000;
    ms = (dt % 1000) * 0.1; //chop to hundredths
    timer_txt.text = ((seconds < 10) ? "0" + seconds : seconds) + ":" + ((ms < 10) ? "0" + ms : ms); //format
}
```

Comment: But you have copied with mistakes... why do you create new variables in the `coundown`? If you want allocate new variables, at least give them same types.

Comment: Without the vars, it created list of undefined properties error messages, so I put the var and the error messages was gone....NEVERMIND I just saw your updated script and it worked perfect now! Thank you very much!