# AS3 display final time

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a function that keeps track of the time elapsed in my main game file that looks like this:

```
public function timeElapsed(milliseconds:int):void 
    {
        var time:Date = new Date(milliseconds);
        var minutes:String = String(time.minutes);
        var seconds:String = String(time.seconds);
        var miliseconds:String = String(Math.round(time.milliseconds)/100);

        if(minutes.length != 2)
        {
            minutes = '0' + minutes;
        }

        if(seconds.length != 2)
        {
            seconds = '0' + seconds;
        }

        trace(minutes + ":" + seconds + "." + miliseconds);
    }
```

What I'm trying to figure out now is how to get it to display the FINAL time, when the player is killed. I have functions handling calls to other files for various events, but at the moment I'm drawing a complete blank on how to get the time to go from here, to displaying on the game over screen, which is it's own separate file.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For calculation of time elapsed in the game, you don't need `Date` class. You should use [getTimer()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#getTimer%28%29) - used to compute relative time. At the start of game register current time elapsed, and format difference as you want.

```
var start: int = getTimer();

//later, check difference
myTextField.text = timeElapsed(start);

function timeElapsed(start : int):String{
    var dt: int = getTimer() - start;
    //format result as you wish
    return someFormatResult;
}
```

`Display final time`, do you want visualise result of time formatting? You could use simple [TextField](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html).

Comment: For formatting I would like to use Minutes:Seconds, Milliseconds isn't really necessary but I thought it'd be a nice addition

Comment: Hm... 1 minute == 1000 ms * 60 seconds

Comment: How would I format the time using `dt`? I'm not sure where to start with that. I know the conversions to get hours, minutes and seconds, I'm just not sure how to go about stripping down the time from `dt`

Edit: Maybe something like this?
`    var hrs:String = (input > 3600 ? Math.floor(input / 3600) + ':' : '');
    var mins:String = (hrs && input % 3600 < 600 ? '0' : '') + Math.floor(input % 3600 / 60) + ':';
    var secs:String = (input % 60 < 10 ? '0' : '') + input % 60;
    return hrs + mins + secs;`

Comment: Formatting to seconds with milliseconds: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22569954/different-timer-with-milliseconds/22571067#22571067

Comment: The issue I'm having now is that the timer is producing an incorrect time (I'm using a trace statement to determine that) plus I cannot get the timer to display in my text field, as it keeps telling me
`Line 143, Column 4 1120: Access of undefined property displayElapsed.` Which is wthe name of my text field for `displayElapsed.text = timeElapsed(start);`

Comment: Did you declared your text field? Like `var displayElapsed: TextField = new TextField();` ?

Comment: I did, but there was an issue with my declaration that caused the problem, so that's fixed now. However, I now need to get the display onto the `GameOverScreen`, and the time is still wrong. It's saying that the time elapsed is 48 seconds when in reality it was between 4-5 seconds.

Comment: Okay so I've got a properly working time elapsed text field working on my game screen. Now I just need to get the final number it lands on to be transferred over to the `GameOverScreen`. Any thoughts?

Comment: It depends on your realisation. If you are working with classes, you could pass it as an argument `new GameOverScreen(timeElapsed(start))` or `var gameOver: GameOverScreen = new GameOverScreen(); gameOver.setTimeElapsed(timeElapsed(start))`